# Is there a VS Code extension that can read/understand/compile GameSalad projects (gsproj)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gamesalad

A few years ago, I created a simple mobile game using a simple but limited game creating platform called GameSalad. I was able to export the game with a key and everything and was able to install it on my own phone to try it, however it needed a MAC computer to do so (even though I edited my entire game using the PC version of their program).

Now I don't have access to a MAC computer anymore, and I don't have the APK anymore. However I have the folders of all the different versions of my game on my PC.

I was wondering if there'd be a way to open the project and compile it as an APK for android using either VS Code or Visual Studio ?

I believe GameSalad was using LUA as a langage. I tried searching for GSPROJ, GameSalad and all combination I could thinkl of in order to find an extension, but didn't find any. Maybe there's a way that I missed ?

While opening my folder in VS Code, the arborescence looks like this :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eai8k.png)

Most files are in .xml , the mainfile (with extension .gsproj) seems empty, and most other scripts/code parts are in a format/extension called ".behavior" and they also seem emtpy.

Any ideas or tips on how I could proceed ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The GameSalad engine that interprets GameSalad's game project files is proprietary so there would be no easy way to compile from VSCode.

The GameSalad Viewer App should work with the current versions of GameSalad for Windows and GameSalad Creator 2 (the web version).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. And yes the viewer works fine on Windows, but in order to compile the game into a standalone APK, even for Android, the fonction to do so was only available on MAC (unless they changed that in a newer version ?)

Comment: The compiling of the APK is done online, so your desktop machine doesn't matter. There is an issue with app signing on Windows for APKs, so you would need to know how to sign via the command line. GameSalad's support team can help you with that.